# Is this a good implementation of StackExchange Redis pipelining?

Tags: asp.net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm starting with REDIS and the StackExchange Redis client. I'm wondering if I'm getting the best performance for getting multiple items at once from REDIS.

Situation:
I have an ASP.NET MVC web application that shows a personal calendar on the dashboard of the user. Because the dashboard is the landing page it's heavily used.

To show the calendar items, I first get all calendar item ID's for that particular month:

```
RedisManager.RedisDb.StringGet("calendaritems_2016_8"); 
// this returns JSON Serialized List<int>
```

Then, for each calendar item id I build a list of corresponding cache keys:

```
"CalendarItemCache_1"
"CalendarItemCache_2"
"CalendarItemCache_3"
etc.
```

With this collection I reach out to REDIS with a generic function:

```
var multipleItems = CacheHelper.GetMultiple<CalendarItemCache>(cacheKeys);
```

That's implemented like:

```
    public List<T> GetMultiple<T>(List<string> keys) where T : class
    {
        var taskList = new List<Task>();
        var returnList = new ConcurrentBag<T>();

        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            Task<T> stringGetAsync = RedisManager.RedisDb.StringGetAsync(key)
                .ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(task.Result))
                    {
                        var deserializeFromJson = CurrentSerializer.Serializer.DeserializeFromJson<T>(task.Result);
                        returnList.Add(deserializeFromJson);
                        return deserializeFromJson;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                });
            taskList.Add(stringGetAsync);  
        }
        Task[] tasks = taskList.ToArray();
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        return returnList.ToList();
    }
```

Am I implementing pipelining correct? The REDIS CLI monitor shows:

```
1472728336.718370 [0 127.0.0.1:50335] "GET" "CalendarItemCache_1"
1472728336.718389 [0 127.0.0.1:50335] "GET" "CalendarItemCache_2"
etc.
```

I'm expecting some kind of MGET command.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed an overload method for StringGet that accepts a RedisKey[]. Using this, I see a MGET command in the monitor.

```
    public List<T> GetMultiple<T>(List<string> keys) where T : class
    {
        List<RedisKey> list = new List<RedisKey>(keys.Count);
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            list.Add(key);
        }

        RedisValue[] result = RedisManager.RedisDb.StringGet(list.ToArray());

        var redisValues = result.Where(x=>x.HasValue);
        var multiple = redisValues.Select(x => DeserializeFromJson<T>(x)).ToList();
        return multiple;

    }
```